# Secure File transmission in C# using AES

Tags: c#, file, aes

I'm trying to read a file on the server (in blocks of 5KB), encrypt the block using AES and send it to the client. On the client, i decrypt the received block, and append to a file to get back the original file.

However, my decrypted block size received on the client differs from the plaintext block which is encrypted on the server.

e.g. 
I have a 15.5 KB exe file, so i have 15.5*1024/5*1024 = 4 blocks (round figure) to encrypt and send to client (The first 3 blocks are of 5120 bytes and last block is 512 bytes in length). On the client however, the blocks decrypted are of size 5057, 4970, 5016 and 512 bytes which equals a file size of 15.1 KB (less than what was actually sent by the server).

Here is my code snippet:

Server (sends the file to client):

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("lcd.exe", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //block size = 5KB
        int blockSize = 5 * 1024;

        //calculate number of blocks in data
        long numberOfBlocks = fs.Length / blockSize;

        if (fs.Length % blockSize != 0) numberOfBlocks++;

        byte[] numberOfBlocksBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(numberOfBlocks);

        //send number of blocks to client
        SendMessage(sw, numberOfBlocksBytes);

        int count = 0, offset = 0, numberOfBytesToRead=0;

        Aes objAes = new Aes();

        while (count < numberOfBlocks)
        {
            byte[] buffer;

            numberOfBytesToRead = blockSize;

            if (fs.Length < offset + blockSize)
            {
                numberOfBytesToRead = (int)(fs.Length - offset);

            }

                buffer = new byte[numberOfBytesToRead];

                fs.Read(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesToRead);

            //encrypt before sending
            byte[] encryptedBuffer = objAes.Encrypt(buffer, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sessionKey), initVector);

            SendMessage(sw, encryptedBuffer);

            offset += numberOfBytesToRead;

            count++;

        }

        fs.Close();
```

Client side code which receives the file:

```
byte[] numberOfBlocksBytes = ReadMessage(sr);

        long numberOfBlocks = BitConverter.ToInt64(numberOfBlocksBytes, 0);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("lcd.exe", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

        //block size = 5KB
        int blockSize = 5 * 1024;

        Aes objAes = new Aes();

        int count = 0, offset = 0;

        while (count < numberOfBlocks)
        {

            byte[] encryptedBuffer = ReadMessage(sr);

            byte[] buffer = objAes.Decrypt(encryptedBuffer, sessionKey, initVector);

            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            offset += buffer.Length;

            count++;

        }

        fs.Close();
```

My AES code for encryption:

```
private const int StandardKeyLength = 16;

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte[] initVector)
    {
        if (key.Length != StandardKeyLength | initVector.Length != StandardKeyLength)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key Length and Init Vector should be 16 bytes (128 bits) in size");
        }

        var bPlainBytes = plainText;

        var objRm = new RijndaelManaged();

        objRm.Key = key;
        objRm.IV = initVector;
        objRm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        objRm.BlockSize = 128;

        var ict = objRm.CreateEncryptor(objRm.Key, objRm.IV);

        var objMs = new MemoryStream();
        var objCs = new CryptoStream(objMs, ict, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        objCs.Write(bPlainBytes, 0, bPlainBytes.Length);

        objCs.FlushFinalBlock();

        var bEncrypted = objMs.ToArray();

        return bEncrypted;
    }
```

My AES code for decryption:

```
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] initVector)
    {
        if (key.Length != StandardKeyLength | initVector.Length != StandardKeyLength)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key Length and Init Vector should be 16 bytes (128 bits) in size");
        }

        var bCipherBytes = cipherText;

        var objRm = new RijndaelManaged();
        objRm.Key = key;
        objRm.IV = initVector;
        objRm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        objRm.BlockSize = 128;

        var ict = objRm.CreateDecryptor(objRm.Key, objRm.IV);
        var objMs = new MemoryStream(bCipherBytes);
        var objCs = new CryptoStream(objMs, ict, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        var streamobj = new StreamReader(objCs);

        var strDecrypted = streamobj.ReadToEnd();

        return (Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strDecrypted));
    }
```

These are the results i got while debugging the while loop which sends file blocks on the server:

Actual File Size sent: 15.5 KB = 15872 bytes

```
Buffer size(plaintext)    Encrypted Buffer Size(Sent)       Offset   Count

5120                           5136                          5120      0

5120                           5136                         10240      1

5120                           5136                         15360      2

 512                            528                         15872      3
```

These are the results i got while debugging the while loop which receives file blocks on the client:

Actual File Size received: 15.1 KB = 15555 bytes

```
Received Buffersize    Decrypted Buffer Size       Offset   Count

5136                           5057                 5057      0

5136                           4970                10027      1

5136                           5016                15043      2

 528                            512                15555      3
```

It is evident that the sending and receiving code is working fine (since encrypted buffer size which is sent  = received buffer size). However, the decrypted buffer size does not match the buffer size (plaintext) at all except for the last block which is of length 512 bytes.

What can be possibly wrong with decryption because of which i'm not receiving the file completely on the client side?

Comment: What about testing encryption without networking first?

Comment: @Zicore I tested but not with huge byte arrays like that of 5120 bytes in length. It was working fine with small byte arrays. Do you doubt if encryption mode or padding are disturbing the output? I'm asking because when i'm using Zero padding, my output file on client is of 14.7KB, which is significantly less than 15.5KB.

Comment: How about built in wcf encryption?

Comment: I'm not using WCF. Even if i could try with that, i really want to understand what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: I have no time to review the code now. I realized it this way: Encrypt all packets independently with a prefixed size of the packet, decrypt them on the other end and join them again.

Comment: @Zicore I had written it the same way as you said before. Initially my buffer was of fixed size of 5KB, regardless of the amount of data read from the file into it. This was encrypted and sent. On the client, it was decrypted and appended to file. The problem is that when you encrypt and send the last packet which is suppose less than the packet size, the client has no way of knowing the size of plaintext after decryption. Hence filesize on the client was actually more than that on the server.

Comment: Encryption should just be another layer of the protocoll. Stack the prefixed size on the encrypted packet and the size of the plain bytes in that encrypted packet. [Size[EncryptedPacket[Size[PlainData]]]]. Anyway the size must be the same on both sides.

Comment: I understand your point, but in my case, the decryption is somehow giving a reduced size. say original packet size is 5120 bytes, then i'm getting 5057 bytes. Now if i stack the size of plaintext i.e. 5120 bytes, i still cannot read more than 5057 bytes from my decrypted packet.

Comment: I bet there is something wrong with encoding and decoding of the string. Avoid encoding/decoding and send the raw bytes of the file.

Comment: @Zicore thanks for the responses. I tried unit testing encryption/decryption component. They worked without any error even for large arrays (5120 bytes). Another thing that i wanted to add is that i'm able to send and receive the file completely if i remove encryption/decryption components. So now it boils down to checking why these components are failing when i try to integrate them.

Comment: You're sending the number of unencrypted packets, not the number of encrypted packets.  You should encrypt it first, then send the number of packets.

Comment: @Amy Do number of unecnrypted packets differ from the number of encrypted packets? Are you suggesting i encrypt the entire file first and then calculate the number of packets?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting.  The problem isn't whether the number of packets is *different*, the problem is that *they could be different*, leading to incorrect behavior.

Comment: @Amy When i encrypt a byte array of size 15.5KB i.e. 15872 bytes, i get an encrypted byte array of size 15886 i.e. 16 bytes more. But this is the same case as of each individual block, if you notice the table i created above. Each block is of size 5120 bytes, but each encrypted block is of size 5136 bytes. It's just that decrypting back the 5136 bytes is not giving me 5120 bytes but something less.

Comment: You create a decent number of objects which implement the `IDisposable` interface (`FileStream`, `Aes`, etc.). These should be wrapped in `using` statements for proper deterministic disposal.

Comment: @user85030, my comment wasn't meant to address your problem.  If it was, I would have posted it as an answer.  I was trying to point out another potential problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being tripped up because in your Decrypt statement you are treating your ciphertext as if it is a string. Specifically, these lines:

```
var streamobj = new StreamReader(objCs);
var strDecrypted = streamobj.ReadToEnd();

return (Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strDecrypted));
```

Instead you want to be calling Read on your CryptoStream to read a raw byte array into a buffer. You can then return that buffer without attempting to coerce it into a string (which is what is happening by using the stream reader).

You should use something more like:

```
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] initVector)
{
    if (key.Length != StandardKeyLength | initVector.Length != StandardKeyLength)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Key Length and Init Vector should be 16 bytes (128 bits) in size");
    }

    var bCipherBytes = cipherText;

    var objRm = new RijndaelManaged();
    objRm.Key = key;
    objRm.IV = initVector;
    objRm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    objRm.BlockSize = 128;

    var ict = objRm.CreateDecryptor(objRm.Key, objRm.IV);
    var objMs = new MemoryStream(bCipherBytes);
    var objCs = new CryptoStream(objMs, ict, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    var buffer = new byte[cipherText.Length];
    int readBytes = objCs.Read(buffer, 0, cipherText.Length);

    var trimmedData = new byte[readBytes];
    Array.Copy(buffer, trimmedData, readBytes);
    return trimmedData;
}
```

I would also suggest you t[ake a look at the encryption utilities I maintain on Snipt](https://snipt.net/Wolfwyrd/encryption-utilities/). Specifically the Symmetric Encrypt and Decrypt methods. Your code as it stands has a lot of using blocks missing and a number of potential resource leaks.

Comment: What is stringSize in the statement Array.Copy(buffer, trimmedData, stringSize); ?

Comment: Array.Copy expects readBytes as long instead of an integer. What is quickest way to parse int to long in C#?

Comment: Array.Copy has no such limitation. It accepts a source, destination and an int length OR a long length. Quickest way to get an int to a long is to cast it "(long)myInt" but it should not be necessary

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm :) I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var streamobj = new StreamReader(objCs);
```

That's pretty unlikely to work well.  The StreamReader will assume that the decrypted data is utf-8 encoded text.  There is no hint whatsoever that this is actually the case from the code that encrypts the data, it takes a byte[].

Use a FileStream instead so no conversion is made at all.  Also helps you avoid the Encoding.Default.GetBytes() data randomizer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This was the reason my code was not working. I followed the steps highlighted by Wolfwyrd and it worked. Upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Quick observation, which may just be my ignorance: Encrypt() method uses default encoding to get the session key bytes. On the receiving end the Decrypt() method uses the sessionKey itself as second parameter, i.e., without getting bytes?

Comment: Actually, i didn't paste the entire code (my bad). So the session key is also a byte array on the client side.